# What are the challenges to landing a spacecraft on Mercury?

Tags: landing, spacecraft-development, lander, mercury

I read that it would be more difficult to land (not crash land) on Mercury or even send a spacecraft in orbit around it because of the gravitational pull of the Sun and the lack of planetary atmosphere. Does current technology allow landing a spacecraft on Mercury to study the surface in detail?

Comment: It's true that Mercury is closer in to the sun so requires a higher delta v to fly there directly. (Higher than Mars I believe.) So the question does have points worth answering if anyone would like to have a go.  (upvoted.)

Comment: I get about 16 km/s from LEO to soft landing on Mercury. And that doesn't take into account Mercury's ~7º inclination or gravity loss during descent. The 100K to 700K temperature swings would be an engineering challenge, I suspect.

Comment: @HopDavid get down quickly into a crater near the terminator?

Comment: Mercury rotates slowly - only a few metres per second - so you could just keep moving camp. :)

Comment: I don't see why budget concerns not withstanding a lander wouldnt be doable.  Heating a powered descent are the only tough bits, which would have to be fully automated because of signal lag

Comment: @SarahBailey Every landing on another planet is fully automated. In any case, see my answer.

Comment: Solar sails, or as Ben Crowell noted in the comments on Pearson's answer, solar-electric propulsion, would make getting into orbit far more fuel-efficient.

Comment: Messenger actually cut back on it's fuel usage considerably by using it's solar panels as solar sails. It still takes quite a bit of fuel for the landing part if nothing else.

Answer (score 8):

The closest we have done thus far is to orbit a spacecraft around Mercury. This was accomplished by a number of flybys first, of Earth, Venus, and Mercury. The mass of [Messenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESSENGER) was about 500 kg, minus fuel. The orbit was still highly elliptical. Per [this chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piNqI.png), to land on Mercury from that orbit requires about 4200 m/s, roughly. That is an enormous amount, more than any other spacecraft to date has had!

There has been some work towards a lander, however. The closest to succeeding is the [BepiColombo mission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BepiColombo), which proposed to send a 7 kg lander to Mercury, known as the Mercury Surface Element. The main mission was approved, but the lander was rejected. Approximately 80% of its mass would be fuel. It would  land near a pole, to avoid the temperature extremes that come due to the long days.

Bottom line, it might be possible, but it would be very difficult. Messenger was a low cost mission, and was able to orbit it. A lander was proposed, but nixed, due to it's expense and expected relatively little scientific gain.

Comment: To get from earth orbit to a circular orbit around Mercury, couldn't you use solar-powered ion propulsion?

Comment: That would work, but that wouldn't work for the landing itself. That still would require 3 km/s of fuel...

Comment: To clarify that, powered descent to Mercury's surface  has to be done over a period of about 10-15 minutes, whereas an ion drive can deliver 3km/s over a period of months. What could work is an ion drive bus stage to get to Mercury, with a lander that uses a chemical rocket to do orbital insertion and landing. Doable but costly.

Comment: @RussellBorogove: Why costly?

Comment: 3 km/s is a lot of delta v to remain stable for such a long time...

Comment: Keeping propellant for a few years not really a problem (witness Juno). But you need a fuel mass fraction of about 80%, as mentioned above, so a half-ton science/power/guidance/engine/landing package means a 2.5 ton craft, which would have to be carried by a still-larger multiple-ion-engine-powered bus stage, which would require a lot of power. On the bright (ha!) side, since it's spending much of its travel time in the inner system, there's lots of solar power to be had...

Comment: Keeping the fuel for that long isn't as much of an issue, except for the fact that it requires a lower ISP fuel, which in tern, as you mentioned, requires a larger fuel mass fraction. The mini lander idea was actually interesting, and the best I think that could be hoped for.